# Running kepler.gl on a laptop without internet connection

Tags: kepler.gl

Is it possible to run kepler.gl on a laptop that does not have an internet connection?

It seems that Mapbox have a product called [Atlas server](https://blog.mapbox.com/atlas-gets-an-upgrade-access-vector-maps-studio-offline-59074b81124a) for offline mapping services.
This product is not free.

Did anyone manage to run fully working kepler.gl offline with or without Atlas?

Does any other solution exist?